# How to migrate from @OneToOne which uses @JoinTable to just @OneToOne?

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, kotlin, jpa, spring-data-jpa

We are restructuring our services and our data. We have 2 entities `Employee`, `CostCenter`

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employees")
data class Employee(
    @Id
    val id: Long? = null,

    @Column(name = "id_dept")
    val departmentId: Long,

    @Column(name = "business_email_address")
    var businessEmailAddress: String? = null,

    @OneToOne
    @JoinTable(
        name = "employee_cost_centers",
        joinColumns = [JoinColumn(
            name = "employee_id",
            referencedColumnName = "id"
        )]
    )
    @JoinColumn(name = "cost_center_id")
    var costCenter: CostCenter? = null
)
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "cost_centers")
data class CostCentre(
    @Id
    val id: Long,
    
    @Column
    var name: String? = null,

    @Column(name = "deleted")
    var isDeleted: Boolean = false
)
```

employees Table

```
| id | id_dept     | business_email_address |
|----|-------------|------------------------|
| 1  | Finance     | finance@example.com    |
| 2  | HR          | hr@example.com         |
| 3  | Development | dev@example.com        |
| 4  | Marketing   | marketing@example.com  |
```

cost_centers table

```
| id  | name                  | deleted |
|-----|-----------------------|---------|
| 10  | FinanceCostCenter     | false   |
| 20  | HRCostCenter          | false   |
| 30  | DevelopmentCostCenter | false   |
| 40  | MarketingCostCenter   | false   |
```

As we are using `@JoinTable` in `Employee` entity, we have a 3rd table which has the mapping between employees and cost centers by the name `employee_cost_centers`.
employee_cost_centers table

```
| cost_center_id | employee_id |
|----------------|-------------|
| 10             | 1           |
| 20             | 2           |
| 30             | 3           |
| 40             | 4           |
```

Now we want to move cost centers to its own micro service. So `cost_centers` table will also move to the new service.
I want to map `costCenter` reference in `Employee` table directly to the 3rd mapping table `employee_cost_centers` by creating a new Entity something like

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee_cost_centers")
data class EmployeeCostCenter(
    @Id
    @Column(name="cost_center_id")
    val costCenterid: Long,

    @Column(name="employee_id")
    val employeeId: Long
)
```

But how should I map this in `Employee` entity?
I am fairly new to the JPA/Hibernate. Any help from the experts much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
@OneToOne
    @JoinTable(
        name = "employee_cost_centers",
        joinColumns = [JoinColumn(
            name = "employee_id",
            referencedColumnName = "id"
        )]
    )
    @JoinColumn(name = "cost_center_id")
    var costCenter: CostCenter? = null
```

by

```
@OneToOne
    @JoinColumns([JoinColumn(
            name = "employee_id",
            referencedColumnName = "id"
        )])
    var employeeCostCenter: EmployeeCostCenter? = null
```

or you can keep the variable name the same, according to your design